# Unable to pass path variable while copying file

Tags: powershell

i am trying to copy one file from local machine to a server path. when i hardcode the paths it does copy the file with the same syntax however when passing it through variable it through an error

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

here is the code:

```
$SourcePath ="C:\Temp\Test.txt"
$DestinationPath ="\\ServerPath\Apps"

write-host $SourcePath 
write-host $DestinationPath 

Copy-Item $SourcePath $DestinationPath
```

Any thought why i am getting this.

Comment: Use `Copy-Item -whatif $SourcePath $DestinationPath` to show what paths copying is going to use. Double-check that the paths are in typed correctly. Also, use `set-strictmode -version 'latest'` to catch mistyped variable names and uninitialized variables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i tried but same error message i am getting.

Comment: No, you didn't. The WhatIf parameter will make copy-item's output to be like `What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: <something>: <something>".` even if the directory does not exist. If variable is uninitialized, you'd get `The variable '<something>' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.`

Comment: Did you execute only the line starting "Copy-Item..."? If so, the variables are unknown. Execute the whole code to test if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wrote $DestinationPath ="\ServerPath\Apps" then this should be correct:

```
$DestinationPath ="\\ServerPath\Apps"
```

Serverpath always start with a double back slash, and depending on escape sequences (different language like C#) you have to double the back slash, so it would be

```
DestinationPath ="\\\\ServerPath\\Apps"
```

Comment: Powershell's escape is backtick (`) , so no need to escape backslashes.

Comment: I tried as you mentioned like DestinationPath ="\\\\ServerPath\\Apps" .. but this also seems not working

Comment: you only need two backslashes. four are needed for C# code. vonPryz stated that the escape character in powershell is `... BTW... did you provide the logon credentials for the server?

Comment: Could you please let me know what would be the exact syntax for DestinationPath

Comment: @Ashis, I am not perfect in Powershell, but to my knowledge, the first code sample in my answer should do.

Comment: Did you execute only the line starting "Copy-Item..."? If so, the variables are unknown. Execute the whole code to test if it works.